# Problem of array - transferring value to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to find another way to calculate different average for some value in a array. The school problem is this : Two arrays, one for working position, the other for the quantity of coffee drunk. We need to define averages for each working position.

```
        var poste = ['P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'O', 'P', 'O'];
        var nbCafe = [3, 2, 1, 20, 4, 2, 5, 11, 32];
        var arrayProgrammeur = new Array();
        var arrayOperateur = new Array();
        var arrayAnalyste = new Array();
        var averageOperateurs;
        var averageProgrammeurs;
        var averageAnalystes;
        var str;

        // séparation des données
        for (var i = 0; i < poste.length; i++) {
            if (poste[i] == 'P') {
                tabProgrammeur.push(nbCafe[i]);
                averageProgrammeur += nbCafe[i];
            } else if (poste[i] == 'A') {
                tabAnalyste.push(nbCafe[i]);
                averageAnalyste += nbCafe[i];
            } else if (poste[i] == 'O') {
                tabOperateur.push(nbCafe[i]);
                averageOperateur += nbCafe[i];
            }
        }


        // calcul de la moyenne
        averageProgrammeurs = averageProgrammeurs / arrayProgrammeur.length;
        averageAnalystes = averageAnalystes / arrayAnalyste.length;
        averageOperateurs = averageOperateurs / arrayOperateur.length;

        document.getElementById('affichage3').innerHTML = "La consommation moyenne de café des opérateurs est de " + moyenneOperateurs + " cafés.<br/>La consommation moyenne de café des programmeurs est de " + moyenneProgrammeurs + " cafés.<br/>La consommation moyenne de café des analystes est de " + moyenneAnalystes + " cafés.";
```

I come from Java and I don't understand why += don't work and why I can't just put a value of an array in another by simply do array.push(array2[i]). I get NaN displayed.

Comment: What version of Java has overloaded `+` for arrays?

Comment: `averageProgrammeur` is not initialized as anything, so adding any number to null or undefined will most likely be NaN.  `tabProgrammeur` also appears to be undefined

Comment: the variables are not initialized and variable names don't match

Comment: `var a; console.log(a); console.log(a + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect only the values in an array and get the average in a second step by calling a function and hand over an array of values. The function gets the total of all values and return the average.

```js
function getAverage(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const value of array) sum += value;
    return sum / array.length;
}

var poste = ['P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'O', 'P', 'O'],
    nbCafe = [3, 2, 1, 20, 4, 2, 5, 11, 32],
    arrayProgrammeur = [],
    arrayOperateur = [],
    arrayAnalyste = [],
    averageOperateurs,
    averageProgrammeurs,
    averageAnalystes;

// séparation des données
for (var i = 0; i < poste.length; i++) {
  if (poste[i] == 'P') {
    arrayProgrammeur.push(nbCafe[i]);
  } else if (poste[i] == 'A') {
    arrayAnalyste.push(nbCafe[i]);
  } else if (poste[i] == 'O') {
    arrayOperateur.push(nbCafe[i]);
  }
}


// calcul de la moyenne
averageProgrammeurs = getAverage(arrayProgrammeur);
averageAnalystes = getAverage(arrayAnalyste);
averageOperateurs = getAverage(arrayOperateur);

console.log(averageOperateurs);
console.log(averageProgrammeurs);
console.log(averageAnalystes);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work very well and it's more optimize than my previous code.